# Iphone Contact list. Sort TableView view alphabetically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting, custom-object, contact-list

### Im making a IPHONE Phonebook app that has an array of contacts(objects). I am trying to sort this array so it displays the lastName in alphabetical order

But nothing seems to work. I'm not sure where i would put my code in the "MasterViewController". HERE IS PART OF MY CODE

My object looks like the following.

```
@interface PhoneBookEntry : Person  
@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *lastName;
@property NSString *address;
@property NSString *phoneNumber;
```

### @end

```
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController
@property NSMutableArray *elements;
@end
```

---

```
@implementation MasterViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.elements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Assume that the array already has elements in it.
I need to sort the "self.elements.lastName" array alphabetically
PLEASE HELP!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.elements sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES]]];
```